# How to create column that names observations from string in corresponding column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm looking to add a column that is renamed based upon the value of a string in the same row.

For example, how could I to create a new column that shows the number at the very end of PlayerID in this table? As such, I want this:

```
PlayerID           
Hank Aaron + 7      
Babe Ruth + 5       
Ted Williams + 2   
Hank Aaron + 5
```

To become this:

```
PlayerID           NewColumn 
Hank Aaron + 7     7 
Babe Ruth + 5      5 
Ted Williams + 2   2 
Hank Aaron + 5     5
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `parse_number` from `readr`

```
df1$NewColumn <- readr::parse_number(df1$PlayerID)
```

---

Or with `sub` to extract the last digit

```
df1$NewColumn <- sub(".*\\+\\s*(\\d+)$", "\\1", df1$PlayerID)
```

#### Update

If we want to extract the digits along with the characters after the `+` and space

```
df1$NewColumn <- sub(".*\\+\\s*(\\d+\\D*)$", "\\1", df1$PlayerID)
```

---

Or another option is `stri_extract_last`

```
library(stringi)
df1$NewColumn <- stri_extract_last_regex(df1$PlayerID, "\\d+\\D*$")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have mentioned earlier, but occasionally there are both a letter and a number following the name in Player ID. For example, one player's ID could be "Hank Aaron + 4i" or "Babe Ruth + 2i." As such, the first two options you provided are unfortunately not going to work, and the 3rd one reads an error "could not find function "stri_extract_last" (when I read it in from the stringr package). When I try to load it in from the stringi package, I get the result t "Assigned data `stri_extract_last_regex(model1a$term, "\\\\d+")` must be compatible with existing data".

Comment: @rogues77 there is a typo.  I meant `stringi` instead of `stringr`

Comment: ```x Existing data has 1109 rows.
x Assigned data has 3 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.```
I am guessing this may be because not every value in the column takes the form of PlayerID described above (as I am trying to modify a tidy regression output df.) Any thoughts on how to remedy this?

Comment: @rogues77 for the first case.  I get `str1 <- "Hank Aaron + 4i"; readr::parse_number(str1)#
[1] 4`,  It was based on a pattern showed in the post

Comment: So unfortunately the stringi command isn't fixing it

Comment: @rogues77 It is all based on the example pattern showed.  If it is a different pattern, the regex needs to be changed.  You mentioned at the very end there is a digit and the `sub` is extracting that digit at the end.  But unfortunately, your new pattern shows that digits are. not at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I should've been more clear, my apologies. I do need the new column to display everything that comes after the plus sign. So if the PlayerID value is "Hank Aaron +4i", I need the new column to read "4i." Is that possible? If necessary I can reorganize the dataframe so that the observations in column  player ID  only take the form "Player name + number/letter.

Comment: @rogues77 I updated the post.  Based on the examples showed, all of them should now work

Comment: Wow you are truly amazing! It worked! I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Hello @akrun, just a question, in the second parameter of sub, `"\\1"` you are substituting the regex expression for a number 1?

Comment: @Alexis It is a backreference for the captured group in brackets (`(...)`).  here, there is only one group and it is the first one.  So, it is `\\1`.  If there are multiple groups, you can call them with numbers \\1, \\2, etc. in the order of captured groups.  i.e. suppose you did `(\\d+)(\\d+)`, the first one is `\\1` and second `\\2`

Comment: Great! Thank you very much @akrun for the kind explanation!